# How to exclude specific fields from a Rails XML output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I am working on a RoR project which outputs XML to RESTful requests.  The problem is it includes the "updated-at" and "created-at" fields in the output.

I have tried using:

```
:exclude -> [ :created_at, :updated_at ]
```

and

```
:exclude -> [ 'created-at', 'updated-at' ]
```

but the output still renders them.  How do I exclude them from the rendering without these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option you want is called `:except`, not `:exclude`. For example:

```
obj.to_xml(:except => [ :created_at, :updated_at ])
```

For more info, see the [Rails API docs for this method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001876).

Comment: This worked perfectly.  What's more, I has discovered that it applies the `:except` to the entire xml, including any `:include`'s.  Cool. Exactly what I needed.